# One program writes to file while other program reads same file c#

Tags: c#, file

1) I have created a program that has opened a twitter stream and writes everything to a file.

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\Database\twitterstream.txt", FileMode.Create);        
    TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    Console.SetOut(sw);
```

2) I have another program that I want to read said text file.

```
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("C:\\Database\\twitterstream.txt"))
        {
            input = sr.ReadLine();
        }
```

Because I want it to be in real time I am trying to have one program write, while at the same time the other program reads, however obviously it is throwing

> "The process cannot access the file 
>   'C:\Database\twitterstream.txt' because it is being used by another
>   process" back at me.

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Add a couple parameters to you FileStream constructor:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(
    @"\Database\twitterstream.txt",
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

See [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: I tried this, however when I did it stopped writing to the file altogether

Comment: @Kate - Sounds like you may have some bugs to work out of your code. I don't have access to the source (and it's likely too much to post here), but I would check for two things: make sure that all of your file handles allow sharing (`File.OpenText` likely locks the file by default) and make sure that you are closing your streams. You must also [flush your stream buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.flush.aspx) when you are finished with a write operation to ensure that the text you've written to the stream actually makes it to the file.